# Angular date comparison

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Pls How to compare two dates below expdate & grantdate and show a popup message on tab out to next field if grantdate is same or less then expdate. It is inside ng-repeat. grantdate is fixed one. user enters grantdate.

```
<tr style="height:40px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0; font-size: 13px;" data-ng-repeat="det in details">
<td><input data-ng-model="det.grantdate" data-ng-disabled="true" type="text" </td>
<td><input data-ng-model="det.expdate" type="text" ></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What have you tried? this is not complicated using one of a variety of different built in directives. It is incumbent on you to attemot to solve problem yourself and ask for help with real problems not ask people to write code for you

Comment: i am new to angular pls give me some idea to implement this

Comment: try with `ng-if` or `ng-show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src= "./scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src= "./scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('stackoverflow', []);
app.controller('datecomparision', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.details = [{grantdate:'01/01/2015',expdate:'12/31/201'}];
    $scope.comparedate = function(grantdate,expdate)
    {
        grantdate = moment(grantdate).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm");;
        expdate = moment(expdate).format("MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm");;
        if (expdate>grantdate)
        {
            alert("expdate : " + expdate+ " is greater than " + " grantdate : " + grantdate );
        }
    }
}])
</script>
<div ng-app="stackoverflow">
    <table ng-controller="datecomparision">
        <tr style="height:40px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0; font-size: 13px;" data-ng-repeat="det in details">
            <td><input data-ng-model="det.grantdate" ng=click="alert('hello!'')" data-ng-disabled="true" type="text" ng-change="comparedate(det.grantdate,det.expdate)"> <td>
                <td><input data-ng-model="det.expdate" type="text" ng-change="comparedate(det.grantdate,det.e`enter code here`xpdate)"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the inputs which might help you:

1. Add a `ng-blur` on the element, on whose focus out you want to show the popup.
2. Call a function on ng-blur which compare the two date datas & show the popup message based on your condition.

Cheers!!